# React - Using eval() to determine if var exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a long time, I'm finding myself checking every nested object if it exists or not.

e.g.
if I need

`someObject.innerThing.evenInnerer.superInerer.length`

I have to do

`let length = someObject && someObject.innerThing && someObject.innerThing.evenInnerer && someObject.innerThing.evenInnerer.superInerer && someObject.innerThing.evenInnerer.superInerer.length;`

to prevent an exception.

So I thought about a way to make it simpler and use an external method (within the class...) like this -

```
  const dataFetcher = (appName, failedFunc) => {
    try {
      let item = eval(appName);
      return item;
    } catch (e) {
      failedFunc && failedFunc();
      return undefined;
    }
  };
```

and do this =>

```
let length = dataFetcher("someObject.innerThing.evenInnerer.superInerer.length", optionalErrorFunc);
if(length == undefined)....
```

and it's cleaner and simpler (IMO).

Are there any downsides to this..?

Thanks

Comment: Your function won't work if `someObject` is in local scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you're sure it's 100% safe, it's always good to avoid `eval()`, as a rule, when there are other options that are just as easy. Using `try-catch` to accomplish this makes things even worse, and your implementation works on the assumption that the variable whose name is being passed in is in scope from the perspective of the `dataFetcher` function, which makes it hard to use and unportable.

In recent versions of JavaScript, you can use conditional chaining:

```
const length = someObject?.innerThing?.evenInnerer?.superInnerer?.length;
```

There are also JS helper libraries that provide functions that help like this.

For example, the `path` function in [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path):

```
const length = path(['innerThing', 'evenInnerer', 'superInnerer', 'length'], someObject);
```

This will produce a value of `undefined` if anything along that path is not present.

If you don't want to involve third-party libraries for this, it's quite trivial to write your own `path` function:

```js
const path = (steps, obj) =>
    steps.reduce(
        (acc, next) => next in acc ? acc[next] : undefined,
        obj
    );

console.log(path(['a', 'b', 'c'], { a: { b: { c: 5 } } }));  // 5
console.log(path(['a', 'b', 'c'], { a: { b: { f: 5 } } }));  // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

### Never use `eval()` in your code, I repeat never!

It's not a good practise to use `eval()` in your code, it's dangerous to use it. If a javascript code is injected using form inputs and you are storing that value in this variable then the browser will execute whatever the user has given as an input using eval.

Instead, use **Optional Chaining** in your code, like this:

`someObject?.innerThing?.evenInnerer?.superInerer?.length`

Above code will either return the `length` or `undefined`
Optional chaining was introduced in ES2020. In this, you use `?` before every `.` to ensure if the property exists on the references

Official documentation link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining